# Passing custom variables via paypal (IPN Question)

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

I've been trying back and forth with this and I finally got PayPal working the way it should. However, i need to pass some variables (user_id, and some small details (numbers) about the product).

Is there any way i can pass custom variables? or variable? I've been looking around on Google and it looks like people is saying different things about this. Some says it not allowed, and some says it's not a problem at all.

Got an example maybe? i assume I'll need a hidden form of some sort?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the `custom` variable: [HTML Variables for Website Payments Standard](https://merchant.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_html_Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables#id08A6HH00W2J). Typically, what I do, is store any info I need in a database and reference it with the PayPal txn_id.